# Does live turf need insulation from roof heat?

Tags: roof, installation, turf

I'm installing grass turf on a rooftop in Jersey City.

It's a flat roof with a lot of sun exposure and occasional strong, swirling winds. I really feel like I need to pad beneath the turf to protect from the heat of the roof, am I correct here? If so, how do I do it?

As well as needing to adhere it i would  also need to be able to remove it when I move.

Comment: Have you considered/calculated weight? Particularly if you get snow on top of the turf?

Comment: I agree, long before you worry about the heat from the roof, you need to ensure your grass doesn't end up on the ground floor. Consult a structural engineer to to a load assessment of your design and your structure. _Then_ worry about whether heat will be an issue. Also, why do you mention the winds but ask about heat? It's like you forgot where you were going...

Comment: These are great points! I will definitely engage a structural engineer, especially as I'm looking to build other items atop the turf installation. 

I mention the wind because my secondary concern beyond getting the turf grounded is keeping it in place once installed as a common climate factor. 

After I get the load assessment and should the weight be supported, is there a padding I should consider placing beneath the turf?

Comment: Where is the heat coming from you are worried about? If it’s just the sunlight, that will take care of itself if you cover the roof with turf.

Comment: Just from sunlight (direct overhead all day)

Comment: You do mean actual grass when you say "grass turf," not astoturf or the like? The part about taking it away with you seems impractical...

Comment: I am open to either the live grass turf or faux astroturf. I own the roof so I'd look to have it add value, so agreed on the need not to remove, ultimately.

Answer (score 2):

A major benefit of a grass/turf or otherwise "green plants" or "living" roof is that you don't have the heat of a typical roof in the sunshine. Storm Water management is an additional benefit to the municipality. Both can result in significant financial incentives/tax breaks as a result.

"Needing to remove it when you move" sounds dubious - this is not a temporary thing easily rolled up and taken away, at least if it's done right. If you don't own the roof, it's unwise to get into this, and if you do own the roof, you sell the green roof with the building (or condo, I guess.)